# How to add UIActivityIndicatorView by using URLSession in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, urlsession

I have the Master-Detail project where I am parsing data from JSON. The purpose is to add UIActivityIndicatorView (by using URLSession) to the DetailsViewController while waiting for data be fetched and loaded to the DetailsViewController. I have tried several ways by starting UIActivityIndicatorView in Master after the following:

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
```

Also I do not know where to stop it, I have tried it in ViewDidLoad() of the DetailViewController (before configureView()):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    configureView()
}
```

But also did not work. I could not find anywhere the information about adding activity indicator by using the state of URLSession. Here I add the code from MasterViewController where I have tried to start the activity indicator:

```
let arrayOfUrls = [ URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Dark+Knight&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Lord+of+the+Rings%3A+The+Return+of+the+King&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Forrest+Gump&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Inception&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Matrix&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Interstellar&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Pianist&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Intouchables&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Departed&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Prestige&apikey=f85dc75e") ]


    for url in arrayOfUrls {

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print (error)
        } else {

            if let data = data {

                do {                        
                    let movie = try JSONDecoder().decode(Movie.self, from: data)
                    print(movie.Title)
                    self.objects.append(movie.Title)
                    self.details.append(movie)
                } catch {                        
                    print("Json Processing Failed")                        
                }
            }
        }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create NetworkService class and do api calls in a func, this way much better.

```
class NetworkService {

let arrayOfUrls = [ URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Dark+Knight&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Lord+of+the+Rings%3A+The+Return+of+the+King&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Forrest+Gump&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Inception&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Matrix&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Interstellar&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Pianist&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Intouchables&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Departed&apikey=f85dc75e"), URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Prestige&apikey=f85dc75e") ]


func getData(completion:@escaping(Movie)->()){
    for url in arrayOfUrls {

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    var movie = Movie()
    if let error = error {
        print (error)
    } else {

        if let data = data {

            do {                        
                movie = try JSONDecoder().decode(Movie.self, from: data)
                print(movie.Title)
                self.objects.append(movie.Title)
                self.details.append(movie)
            } catch {                        
                print("Json Processing Failed")                        
            }
        }
    }
     completion(movie)
    }
    task.resume()
}

}
```

}

In view Controller call your func:

```
  let networkService = NetworkService()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    networkService.getData { result in
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    //result your movie data do whatever yo want it
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //If you need to reload tableview or etc. do here
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What about DetailViewController? Activity indicator should appear there after navigating from Master to Detail and should disappear when data will be loaded from Master to Detail. I should not change anything in DetailViewController?

Comment: Where do you loading data? Master, Detail?

Comment: Loading data to Detail and need to have indicator in Detail screen as soon as Detail screen is opened/loaded (navigated from Master to Detail screen) and keep that indicator till data will be loaded in Detail Screen (the data I have parsed from Json in Master).

Comment: Show activity indicator in Master than. Don't need to show indicator detail. After loading data stop activity indicator and perform your segue.

Comment: Do you mean I should still start and stop activity indicator in Master in the way you have showed in above code and just create UIActivityIndicatorView in Details and connect them?

Comment: No need to create activityIndicator in Details View Controller. Load your data in Master Controller and run activityIndicator. After load complete, stop activityIndicator and perform your segue. Pass your data to detail in -override func prepareForSegue- method. When you show Detail Controller, you don't need run activityIndicator. Because your data already loaded in your Master and you passed it to Detail Controller.